# Wallet Connect: No RPC Url available for chainId: 137

Tags: javascript, ethereum, wallet-connect, matic

[image]

I am trying to create a [WalletConnect](https://walletconnect.org/) provider.

I am using the [@walletconnect/web3-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@walletconnect/web3-provider) package along with [Web3Modal](https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal) for UI.

I am instantiating the `WalletConnectProvider` using my [Infura](https://infura.io/) client ID

```
let web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
    network: "matic",
    cacheProvider: true,
    providerOptions: {
        walletconnect: {
            package: WalletConnectProvider,
            options: {
                infuraId: "c22c90a767684c5fbd7257da57802b35" ,
            },
        },
    },
});

web3Modal.clearCachedProvider();
await web3Modal.connect();
```

When I run my app and connect my wallet, I get the following error:

```
Error: No RPC Url available for chainId: 137
```

I am trying to connect to the [Polygon network](https://polygon.technology/) (which is `chainId 137`).

Infura does seem to support the Polygon Mainnet chain.

Also, I have this chain added to my MetaMask mobile wallet, which is the wallet I am using when connecting to WalletConnect.

So it should work..

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using this RPC URL -
`https://matic-mainnet.chainstacklabs.com`

More references can be found here - https://github.com/maticnetwork/static/blob/master/network/mainnet/v1/index.json

Comment: Thanks, you lead me on the right track. I needed to add the following option when instantiating `WalletConnectProvider`: `rpc: {137: "https://matic-mainnet.chainstacklabs.com"}` from [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@walletconnect/web3-provider#rpc-url-mapping). This seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Can you share the code? I am having the exact same error. I have tried adding rpc like this: 
```const provider = new WalletConnectProvider({
  rpc: {
    43113: "https://api.avax-test.network/ext/bc/C/rpc"
  },
  infuraId: INFURA_ID,
});
```
got another error: typeError e is not a contructor.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the exact same issue. Here is how I resolved this error:

```
import WalletConnectProvider from '@walletconnect/web3-provider';
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal';
```

```
const options = new WalletConnectProvider({
  rpc: {
    137: 'https://matic-mainnet.chainstacklabs.com',
  },
  infuraId: INFURA_ID,
});

const providerOptions = {
  walletconnect: {
    package: WalletConnectProvider, // required
    options: options,
  },
};
```

```
const web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
    network: 'mainnet',
    cacheProvider: true,
    providerOptions, 
  });
}

const provider = await web3Modal.connect();
```